# Complex Integration Over Square

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate the following counterclockwise over $C$: $$\int_C\frac{5z^3+5 \sin(z)}{(z-2i)^3} dz,$$ where $C$ is the boundary of the square with vertices  $\pm 3, \pm3i$.

I imagine $4$ integrals need to be summed?

How do you calculate the boundaries and then set up the integrals?

Answer (score 3):

If you know residue theorem, you should use it. Otherwise, you're going to have a very bad time.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you have studied Cauchy's integral formula

> $$ f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\, dz, $$

then you can use it.